# Как прочитать весь pickle файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется

```
def read_from_pickle(path): #функция работает не правильно, в консоль ничего не поступает
with open(path, 'rb') as file:
    try:
        while True:
            yield pickle.load(file)
    except EOFError:
        pass

my_file = open("E:\zw.txt", "ab+")
pickle.dump(main_func(), my_file) #ввод данных из функции "main_func()", данные успешно появляются в файле
read_from_pickle("E:\zw.txt")
```

Нужно вывести в консоль все строки файла, но поскольку функция работает не правильно (в консоль ничего не поступает), это не удается сделать. Как решить эту проблему?
Кусок кода брал отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067957/how-to-read-pickle-file

Comment: В консоль выводится функцией print().

Comment: @Эникейщик действительно, спасибо

Answer (score -2):

Решение:
изменить строку `yield pickle.load(file)`
на `print(pickle.load(file))`